# Save WooCommerce OrderData in ACF Field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

My goal is to save WooCommerce order data into an ACF Field in the backend of WordPress.
For this project every order which is completed generates a new post in my custom post type named 'groeiprocessen'. The code for this function looks like this and works perfectly.

```
    function create_post_after_order( $order_id ) {
  if (  $order_id instanceof WC_Order ){
    return;
  }
    
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $order_items = $order->get_items(); 
    
    foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item_data ) {
    $product = $item_data->get_product();
    $content.= $item_data->get_quantity();
    $content.= $product->get_name();
  }
    
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title'   => "Order {$order_id}",
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_status' => 'private',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_type' => 'groeiproces',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
  );    
  $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'create_post_after_order', 10, 1 );
```

Right now the product name and quantity gets saved in the post content, which looks like this.

Groeiproces_post

[image]

As you can see I created to ACF Fields under the content field. Now my question is: How can I save the quantity data for the right product in the ACF Fields under my post?

**Field ID's**

acf-field_6163f2e1542e1

acf-field_61640103002c9

**Field names**

acf[field_6163f2e1542e1]

acf[field_61640103002c9]

I would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

I was able to upgrade my code to this:

```
function create_post_after_order( $order_id ) {
  if (  $order_id instanceof WC_Order ){
    return;
  }
    
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $order_items = $order->get_items(); 
    
    foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item_data ) {
    $product = $item_data->get_product();
    $qty.= $item_data->get_quantity();
    $name.= $product->get_name();
  }
    
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title' => "Order {$order_id}",
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_status' => 'private',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_type' => 'groeiproces',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
  );    
  $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    
    $classs_field_key = 'field_61645b866cbd6';
    $classs_subfield_key = 'field_61645b916cbd7';
    $classs_items = array($name,$name,$name);

    foreach ($classs_items as $classs_items_value) {
        $classs_value[] = array($classs_subfield_key => $classs_items_value);
        update_field($classs_field_key, $classs_value, $post_id);
    }
    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'create_post_after_order', 10, 1 );
```

I can now save the product name and quantity in an array field. But the problem is that the order lines are combined. How can separate the order lines, so that every order line is one array line?

Current situation

[image]

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Since you call wp_insert_post you can call after that save_post() -https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. Could you give me some more insight in how I should implement that in my code?

Comment: You need repeater field for this. You want each product data to be saved in separated field right ? Check the acf forum - https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/wp_insert_post-and-repeater-fields/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to upgrade my code. But I got one problem left.